# x264: Optimal settings to have i-frames coincide with shot boundaries?

Tags: h.264, video-encoding, x264

I would like to encode a video using `x264` in such a way, that the keyframes (a.k.a. *i-frames*) are coinciding with shot boundaries (a.k.a. *cuts*).

for testing, I used the following encoder settings (reference: http://www.chaneru.com/Roku/HLS/X264_Settings.htm):

```
keyint=500:min-keyint=10:scenecut:40
```

but from the looks of it scene changes are ignored entirely, and keyframes simply inserted every 500 frames.

[image]

`scenecut:40` being the default value, is my result expected behavior? or is it an indication, that something is not quite right?

thanks a lot in advance

---

edit:

the complete encoder settings look like this (in `handbrake`):

[image]

---

TL;DR:

it was a typo :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your settings screenshot it looks like it result in disabling of scenecut (`scenecut=0` in x264 Unparse) because you used `:` as separtor of parameter name and value for scenecut instead of `=`.
So either change your additional params to:

```
keyint=500:min-keyint=10:scenecut=40
```

or remove scenecut from it at all i.e.:

```
keyint=500:min-keyint=10
```